# statically setting image not displaying

Tags: java, android, static, imageview, visibility

I have an ImageView that when the activity starts needs to be hidden. Depending on the result of some other function I want to statically give it an image and set it to visible.

```
static boolean started = false;
static ImageView imageView;
static TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    started = true;
}

public static void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    if (started) {
        if (success) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.someImage);
            textView.setText("someText");
        }
        else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.someOtherImage);
            textView.setText("someOtherText");
        }
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is the image is clearly being set as the Activity reshapes itself however it is just blank where the image should be.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all it is not a good practice to keep view references in static variables as it may cause memory leaks. Where are you calling setSuccess() method?

Comment: It gets called within a message received class so when a push message is received it can update the UI appropriately